# FindBugs shows only the first occurrence of a bug

Tags: eclipse, static-analysis, findbugs

FindBugs seems to show only the first occurrence of a particular bug in each method. This occurs in Eclipse as well as in the FindBugs stand-alone client.
How can I configure FindBugs to show *all* occurrences?

Example:

```java
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

public class Bar
{
    public void meth(@Nonnull final String pArg) {
        System.out.println(pArg);
    }

    public void foo() {
        String s = null;
        meth(s);      // <<== bug marker here (NP_NONNULL_PARAM_VIOLATION)
        meth(null);   // no bug marker here
        meth(s);      // and none here either  :-(
    }
}
```

Im am using the latest FindBugs 2.0.2 Eclipse plugin (with Eclipse 3.6).

The problem appears to depend on the bug pattern. For example, I see more than one hit per method with `DLS_DEAD_LOCAL_STORE`, but not with `NP_NONNULL_PARAM_VIOLATION`. The latter is shown above.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm using eclipse 4.2 and findbugs 2.0.1 and I see more than one of at least some bug instances in a method.  Can you add a small example?

Comment: @TimK Sure - Just added the example above.

Comment: I see the same thing and can't explain it.  Even another instance with a different method and string isn't reported.  I tried an example with two RC_REF_COMPARISON bugs and it reported both.

Comment: For what it's worth, in eclipse 4.2 if you enable null analysis, eclipse itself reports problems on all three of those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Findbugs only checks those lines of code for this specific error, which can actually be reached according to a control flow analysis. With your 3 method invocations, the first one leads to a NPE, therefore the second and third will never be reached.

There have been similar bug reports for previous versions: http://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/bugs/980/

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. FindBugs 1.3.9 used to scan the entire method though. The nullness detector seems to have lost this feature.